# Laravel5: Controller and Model Undefined variable: title

Tags: php, laravel

So i was following a Laravel with Traversy Media well you know this guy already, He makes tutorials on Youtube but i have problem with my codes i tried to copy and what he did in the video but i still got some errors

this is the error i got

Undefined variable: title (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\centralsocial2\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php)

```
  --- PostsController.php ---
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('posts.index')->with('posts' , $posts);
}
```

im extending the post to this

```
@extends ('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <h1> Posts </h1>

  @if(count($posts) > 1)
    @foreach($posts as $post)
      <h3> {{$post->$title}}</h3>
      <p> {{$post->$body}} </p>
    @endforeach
  @else 
    <p> no posts found </p>
  @endif
@endsection
```

Is the Laravel he was using in the video outdated? Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: It's `$post->title`, not `$post->$title`. And `$post->body`

Comment: @kerbholz oh i did not notice that Thank you so much :) all love from PH

Answer (score 5):

In the view file you have to remove $ after $post variable in loop, like this:

```
@extends ('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <h1> Posts </h1>

  @if(count($posts) > 1)
    @foreach($posts as $post)
      <h3> {{$post->title}}</h3>
      <p> {{$post->body}} </p>
    @endforeach
  @else 
    <p> no posts found </p>
  @endif
@endsection
```

Comment: yep my bad haha anyway Thank youu :)